# Trying to get a random line from a file, getting TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror

I am working on a python project that needs to read a random line from a text file so I tried to insert a variable that is a random number into the lines[].strip() function in python
and got the error: `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`
here is the code:

```
rand = random.randrange(0, 10)
file = open("file.txt", "r")
line1 = lines[rand].strip()
```

Comment: Please take more care when posting your code. The code as posted won't give that error: it won't work at all in fact, because you don't define `lines`.

Comment: But wherever you do define `lines`, you clearly make it an `int`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you are not reading the file properly and that your `lines` variable is an integer. Showing us more of your code would help. Getting a specific line from a file can be done in multiple ways. Here's a few demos:

Either read lines until you are at the line you want:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f):
        if num == some_number:
            print(line)
            break
```

Or read the whole file, split the lines and access your line by a specific index. This method is not advised if your files are large and you just need one line.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines() 
    print(data[some_number])
```

Finally, you can use [linecache](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html):

```
import linecache
line = linecache.getline('file.txt', some_number)
print(line)
```